# You can see me, but you can not look at me

Tags: riddle, word

You can see me, but you can not look at me. 
I can be gone or around for months at a time. 
I am middle-aged, but I don't hear you telling me that.
In finnish, I could be yours.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are

> The Sun

You can see me, but you can not look at me.

> You can see the sun in the sky but looking directly at it could damage your eyes

I can be gone or around for months at a time.

> There are places in the world where the sun doesn't set ([Midnight Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_sun)) or doesn't rise ([Polar Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_night)) for months at a time.

I am middle-aged, but I don't hear you telling me that.

> The sun is a middle-aged star but is also approximately 4.6 billion years ago, so not middle-aged in human terms.

In finnish, I could be yours. (thanks to jafe)

> "sun" is dialectal Finnish for "sinun" (yours). 
>  *Originally*: The Finnish for sun is aurinko which sounds like *our* inko.

Comment: Nice! For the last line, rot13("fha" vf qvnyrpgny Svaavfu sbe "fvaha" (lbhef)).

Comment: @jafe Thanks, that works much better.

Comment: It was supposed to be easy, but maybe it was too easy :)

Comment: @K2_ It's always difficult to tell. I think it's quite good as several of the lines are not obvious indications of the answer, it's really the first line that points us in the right direction.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought. Dunno why... must be my previous riddle ;) Nice job, hexomino!